# Python alternative way to replace certain characters from String

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have "hihwru" and I want to replace "wr" with "oware", without using replace method in Python.

Below is my code:

```
def Rep(str,chr,Rchr):
    if chr in str:
        str1=str.replace(chr,Rchr)
        print(str1)
    else:
        print("character is not present in the string to replace")

Rep("Hihwru","wr","oware")
```

I want this to use with out replace method. How can I do it (using Python)???

Comment: You can turn the string into a list, replace a slice in the list, and join it back to a string. Or use `re.sub`. But why? Do you just want to avoid that particular method, or is this an assignment to write your own replace method?

Comment: yes dude, this is my assignment work...., @tobias_k

Comment: Well, if this is an assignment to write your own replace method, then just using `re.sub` instead of `str.replace` probably won't give you much credit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RegExp, view [ideOne](http://ideone.com/855S01)

```
import re

def Rep(str,chr,Rchr):
    if chr in str:
        str1 = Rchr if chr else None
        result = re.sub(chr, str1, str)
        print(result)
    else:
        print("character is not present in the string to replace")

Rep("Hihwru","wr","oware")
```